# Android click Highlight issue: After updating to Android studio 2.2 preview 3

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-theme, android-studio-2.2

I am having this weird issue, for android OS below lollipop. When i click on Toolbar option menu or navigation drawer etc i am getting weird black edges as a highlight. Please see attached pic as an example

[image]

here is my theme for this activity (using AppCompactActivity as Base Activity)
`

```
<style name="NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

`

Comment: This issue appears because of problems with 9-patch images in Android plugin for Gradle (2.2.0 alpha-*). They work as usual png images and don't stretch as 9-patch files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the issue, after the update my Android Plugin for Gradle was also updated to `2.2.0 alpha-3` but i changed it back to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'  // stable version.
```

With this minor tweak now this issue is resolved.

Note: You can either just wait for stable 2.2.0 version or try the next update.