# Gradle Sync failed could not find constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha2

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-constraintlayout

**Problem :**

```
Error:Could not find com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha2.
Required by:
myapp:app:unspecified
```

**Background :**
Android Studio 2.2 P 1

Comment: I was working with AS 2.2 P 3 and it was fine

Comment: I just updated to AS2.2-alpha7... and it started error-ing out on me too.

Answer (score 331, accepted):

Support libraries for `ConstraintLayout` could not be installed/updated.

Just open `Preferences` > `Appearance & Behavior` > `System Settings` > `Android` and move to `SDK Tools` tab. Check the following fields and install.

[image: Preferences]

Comment: For those who have these libraries installed but gradle is still complaining, check `jmartinalonso`'s answer below. It is extending this answer.

Comment: Note: `Preferences` is actually `File` > `Settings` on Windows.

Comment: In my case I couldn't find AndroidSDK as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42252340/cant-find-android-sdk-on-android-studio-preferences) .So I executed `./sdkmanager "extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.0-beta4"` from android-tools/bin.

Comment: Great helped me, but we need to sync and update both [ gradle and sdk tools versions]

Comment: I'm running on Ubuntu, and my ~/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository was owned by root:root.  I chowned it to my user, and I could then update the library.

Comment: As of Android Studio 2.3.3 on Windows, the mouse clicks required are File-->Settings-->Appearance & Behavior-->System Settings-->Android SDK-->SDK Tools tab.
Then check "ConstraintLayout for Android" and "Solver for ConstraintLayout."
Finally, Build-->Rebuild Project

Comment: My current version is 3.0 i have tried your ways but its not solved :(

Answer (score 132):

In my case, that support libraries for ConstraintLayout were installed, but I was adding the incorrect version of ConstraintLayout Library in my build.gradle file. In order to see what version have you installed, go to `Preferences` > `Appearance & Behavior` > `System Settings` > `Android SDK`. Now, click on `SDK Tools` tab in right pane. Check Show Package Details and take note of the version.

[image]

Finally you can add the correct version in the `build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 15):

The fix is to update the android gradle plugin in your build.gradle.

This should work:
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha2'

Or you can use the latest:
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha3'

Comment: Be careful with using 2.2.0-alpha3 there is a bug with Toolbar on Android 4.x http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37812115/android-click-highlight-issue-after-updating-to-android-studio-2-2-preview-3

Answer (score 12):

My problem was, that the SDK Tools updated it to the latest version, in my case it was 1.0.0-alpha9, but in my gradle dependency was set to

compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8'
So, you can change your gradle build file to

compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'
Or you check "Show package details" in the SDK Tools Editor and install your needed version. See screenshow below. Image of SDK Tools

[image]

Answer (score 11):

1. Ensure you have the maven.google.com repository declared in your module-level build.gradle file

   `repositories {
             maven {
                   url 'https://maven.google.com'
             }
       }`

2.Add the library as a dependency in the same build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
      compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I updated my android gradle plugin to `2.2.0-alpha4` and constraint layout dependency to `1.0.0-alpha3` and it seems to be working now

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. Gradle updated itself after popup but not the constraint dependency

Answer (score 6):

First I tried everything that I have read on stackoverflow...from updating gradle to XY version, to updating ConstraintLayout to XY version...I even update my SDK tools and Android Studio to the latest version...but nothing was working.

The only solution that worked for me was that I delete ConstraintLayout library from gradle and SDK, then I opened random xml layout and in **Design view** under **Palette** section search for **ConstraintLayout**. If you have successfully deleted library from your project then you will be able to install the library from there if you double clicked on **ConstraintLayout** element.

That has create next line in my app build.gradle:

```
'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta1'
```

In my project build.gradle I have this:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
```

Android studio version 2.2.2

Comment: Yes I agreed with your answer

Answer (score 5):

Alpha version is no longer available !

```java
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
```

Comment: Use latest version of contraint-layout

Comment: Where would one add this line of code?  I have latest android version 3.6 and I do not have a Support Repository option in SDK Tools

Answer (score 3):

Just to make sure that in studio version 2.3 you won't see a dropdown near constraint-layout in sdk tools, it will by default install the latest version

To get the desired version check the box saying show package details and boom you can now choose the desired version you want to install

Comment: I was stuck on this until I saw your post I needed a specific older version of these.  Great tip!

Answer (score 1):

gradle `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha6`

constraint layout dependency `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha4`

works for me

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a completely different issue. When I installed constraint dependancy in SDK tools, the tools somehow wrote them into the *wrong* directory. That is

`/home/${USER}/Android/Sdk/extras/+m2repository+/com/.../constraint`

**instead of**

`/home/${USER}/Android/Sdk/extras/+android+/+m2repository+/com/.../constraint`

**Remedy:**

Just copy the `1.0.0-alpha*` directories into the latter path

Answer (score 1):

While updating SDK tools, a dilog box presented with Constraint layout version that is going to get installed. Note that and update your dependency based on that. In my case it was installing beta3.

I changed my dependency like below. After that it worked.

compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta3'

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to remove the previous versions first and download the latest one instead. v1.0 stable was released on Feb 23rd. [image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had a multi-module project called "app" and "sdk".  The "sdk" module is the one where I had added the constraint layout library.  I got the error when I tried to incorporate "sdk" into a new multi-module project called "app2".  The solution was to ensure I had added the Google Maven Repository to the project-level build.gradle file for "app2".  The Google Maven Repository can be added by putting "google()" under `allprojects.repositories` in the project-level build.gradle file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using AS 2.3 and I wanted to use the currently latest ConstraintLayout 1.1.3, but the latest version in my Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android was 1.0.2.

To use ConstraintLayout 1.1.3, I updated my AS from 2.3 to currently latest 3.2.1, com.android.tools.build:gradle from 2.2.2 to 3.2.1, gradle from 3.3 to 4.6 and buildToolsVersion from 25.0.0 to 28.0.3.

I also added maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } to the Maven repositories in the project-level build.gradle file and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a heads up to those still searching for this.

ConstraintLayout 1.0.1 and lower have been deprecated by maven.

For a list of available constraint layouts that can be downloaded, see below:

https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=Constrain#com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout

The easiest solution at the moment, is to change

`implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta1'`

to

`implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'`

Answer (score 0):

I used com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha2 with classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0', it worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm too late, but in case someone has still the error after an update of ConstraintLayout and Solver over the SDK Tools, maybe this solution could help: [Error:(30, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38450414/error30-13-failed-to-resolve-com-android-support-constraintconstraint-layo/39815613#39815613)

Answer (score 0):

Its available in androidx as following package

```
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your constraint layout dependency to the relevant version from '1.0.0-alpha2'. In my case, I changed to the following.
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha5'

Answer (score 0):

I added the following script in **build.gradle(app)** under  **android** & I was able to compile.

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
    targetCompatibility 1.8
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Similar issue solved by Reinstalling Android Studio.

Comment: I guess a simpler solution is expected.

Answer (score -4):

[image]

i'm try constraint layout dependency update available 1,and plugin gradle alpha-6,it worked