# Error:(30, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha4

Tags: android

[image]

Error:(30, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha4

Comment: try upgrading your gradle. read more at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37992187/gradle-sync-failed-could-not-find-constraint-layout1-0-0-alpha2

Comment: Updated.Still not working.

Comment: You have to have Android Studio 2.2 Preview to use ConstraintLayout, I'm getting the same error in android studio 2.1

Comment: Please look at that [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40245159/4260491). Maybe will help you! ;)

Comment: In my case, the error is because "constraint-layout" was downloaded with a different md5 checksum. However, I found it still existed on my disk. So I just ignore the error and everything works fine.

Answer (score 13):

I've found the fix:

- Download `Android Studio 2.2 Preview 7`
- Update SDK Tools to the latest `25.2.1`
- Download `ConstraintLayout and Solver for ConstraintLayout` in SDK Manager as per image below
- Add `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha5` to gradle.build

[image: ConstraintLayout and Solver]

Comment: I think SDK Tools version number should be 25.2.1

Comment: for historical purposes I left the old versions of the answer, but using AS2.2 and downloading the needed libs from Support Repository is enough.

Answer (score 6):

Well, I had the issue, that I updated the the ConstraintLayout and Solver dependecy like it was suggested it in the posts above. But still had the issue. My problem was, that the SDK Tools updated it to the latest version, in my case it was 1.0.0-alpha9, but in my gradle dependency was set to

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8'
```

So, you can change your gradle build file to

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'
```

Or you check "Show package details" in the SDK Tools Editor and install your needed version. See screenshow below. [image: Image of SDK Tools]

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio select:
SDK Manager -> SDK Tools -> check 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha4' in bottom of list and press 'OK' for installing this and updates, proposed by Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing of this helps ,
Create a new android Project and check its build.gradle(module:app) and check for constraint compile/implementation.
Copy that to your app build.gradle(module:app).

That should do the work :-)