# Using version 1.0.0-alpha7 of the constraint library, which is obsolete

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm starting using Android Studio 2.2 and trying to play with ConstraintLayout but when I let android studio add it automatically it showed me that error

```
Using version 1.0.0-alpha7 of the constraint library, which is obsolete
```

when I try to upgrade it using quick fix I get that error

```
Error:Could not find com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8.
```

I think this is a bug in Android Studio. What should I do to fix it?

my current solution is to suppress the error.

Comment: What version of the Android Plugin for Gradle are you using, from your top-level `build.gradle` file? Have you downloaded the `ConstraintLayout` bits in the SDK Manager?

Comment: thanks, this was my problem, 
I was thinking gradle will download it like any other library,
and what's more confusing is that I need to use the new SDK Manager.

Comment: My understanding was that Gradle *was* going to be able to download the `ConstraintLayout` artifacts automatically as needed. Perhaps that is being held off until `ConstraintLayout` is fully released, rather than being in an alpha state.

Comment: Please look at that [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40245159/4260491). Maybe will help you! ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to install `ConstraintLayout for Android` inside `Support Repository` package on `SDK Tools` category of `SDK Manager`.

Comment: Yeah sure @humazed, I answered it in more details for those weren't able to find 'em.

Answer (score 18):

`File` - `Settings` - `Appearance & Behavior` - `System Settings` - `Android SDK`

Remember choose "show detail". You should see the latest version of Constraint Layout.
[image]

Comment: This is the first time I find this window helpful, I still use the old one. Thanks guo that solved my problem =)

Comment: Note: on Ubuntu you must start Android Studio as root, otherwise the Android SDK menu entry is not visible

Comment: I even didn't know there is such an option :( Thanks Guo

Comment: @Hesam You need to check the box on the right bottom "Show Package Details"

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this warning because you are using `older version` of constraint layout while you have `newer version` available.
Go to your **sdk manager**->**sdk tools**->**Support Repository**->**ConstraintLayout For Android** and then  tick the **Show Package Details** checkbox to find the available versions of constraint layout and install the newest version and update your **build.gradle(App Level)**.

Up until now the newest version is **constraint-layout:1.0.2** so use this.