# Can't find 'Android SDK' on Android studio preferences

Tags: android-studio

i'm looking for the option 'Android SDK' that should be on Android studio at : 
Preferences -> Appearance & Behaviour -> System Settings.

I've recently installed ndk on my laptop(running on mac os), it might made the change.

Needless to say i've tried all the 'normal' resets to Android Studio.

https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#sdk-manager

[image: System Settings]

Comment: Hi Dus ,

I am facing the exact same issue on my mac with Android Studio v2.2.3. Did you receive any help? I see that you have asked this 21 hours ago.

Comment: hi @GautamM. tried everything i could think of. Ended up uninstalling Android Studio, and re installing it (kept the sdk installation so it didn't take a long time)

Comment: Hi Dus,

I tried your way, however no change. Do I need to do anything more?

Did this work for you?

Comment: @GautamM. if you uninstalled android studio and it didn't work, i'd clean the sdk as well. Are you running on mac or windows ?

Comment: tried uninstalling Studio.. Installed new SDK.. Still no luck.. Not sure how to get this to work..

Im on mac.. Sierra OS

Comment: Finally Updating to Android Studio version 2.3 solved the issue.

Also, now the 'Launch Standalone SDK Manager' option is not present in this new studio version.

Clicking on the toolbar SDK Manager Icon launches in built manager window.

Strange ways!

Answer (score 1):

This icon in circle is SDK Manager. Below window you can see "Launch standalone SDK Manager" if you need this representation, though they are almost same.
[image: SDK Manager]

Answer (score 0):

to solve this problem go to settings -> languages and frameworks ->Android SDK -> then sdk tools  now you can find your sdk tools and update them