# Importing android project error

Tags: android

Hi guys when im importing my android project I am getting an error 'Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint.layout:1.0.0.Please help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37992187/gradle-sync-failed-could-not-find-constraint-layout1-0-0-alpha2

Answer (score 0):

try `com.android.support.constraint:constraint.layout:1.0.0`. 
It looks like a simple typo.

Comment: It is their sorry I missed the c but im.getting this error

Comment: Post the dependencies section of your build.gradle file

Comment: how do you do that im fairly new to android id you dont mind ill appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the Google maven repository? Your `allprojects` part of your 
project's build.gradle file should look something like this

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}
```