# Android studio basic activity shows blank

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, layout

Please guys i am currently working on a project, but each time i try implementing android basic activity, it shows appears blank, can someone kindly assist me with what to do. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle Sync failed could not find constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37992187/gradle-sync-failed-could-not-find-constraint-layout1-0-0-alpha2)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Definitely people here will help you but please provide relevant information i.e. your Activity code, Layout code and other details for example any compile, runtime or other error. Thanks!

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wjKuPq6GvCVT7lGjFQmZ9DPppOFzZKO

Comment: i cant add a picture to my post because i am new here, but kindly check out these links please:   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wjKuPq6GvCVT7lGjFQmZ9DPppOFzZKO,    https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZIcTm9ee7c_iUACBNOWesNojBuzgZ52-                             ,https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wjKuPq6GvCVT7lGjFQmZ9DPppOFzZKOy,                                                  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_03HykIOYHpi-KZ2sW4qSKJc5xBI4aW6

Comment: thanks @DetainedDeveloper but that is not the fault, kindly check out those picture above

Answer (score 1):

Try to following code replace your content_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

</RelativeLayout>
```