# Problem with rendering, how can I solve it?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem with the preview of my app.

[image]

In the log file i have a few errors :

[image]

This is a group project but I am the only one encountering this problem. I just downloaded Android Studio so I did not touch anything in the settings.

Any idea?

Comment: I think you should find what you need in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37992187/gradle-sync-failed-could-not-find-constraint-layout1-0-0-alpha2)

Comment: @kipo just add `implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'` to app's build.gradle dependancy section

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried your solution but it didn't hekp. Do you have any other idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Add constraint layout dependency in `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but sadly it doesn't change anything. I added the line in the build.graddle file then synced my project then restarted it but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Just click the blue text that prompt in your console

[image]

or try to add these into your gradle (app level)

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

And you can update them to latest version if Android Studio tells you there's a new version.

Comment: Nothing happens when I click on the blue text you indicated. I also tried to add the two lines in the build.gradle file but nothing changed. But I have a message in the event log section telling me to migrate my project to Gradle, maybe this is what it's all about ?

Comment: I think you should. 
It tells you that your AndroidStudio didn't know what is `Constraint-Layout`, so you need to add that to gradle and sync/rebuild to let it know how to render the `constraintLayout`
If it's possible, I'll recommend you use the latest suggested version of gradle / AndroidStudio / appcompat/support libs. (remember to backup first, it might get quite annoying in the beginning)