# I'm having a trouble with Missing CLASSES in Layout Preview

Tags: java, android

I'm having trouble with ***missing classes***.
"The following classes could not be found:" messages making me sick.

I've tried ***most of answers*** in stackoverflow answers and it didn't helped at all.
I create the file with navigation bar project then applied my files in to Firebase.

I tried to Change the dependencies and Style files.
    here is my Dependency :

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
```

and here is my style code

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"     
parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

I've already changed  Apptheme part ***Theme.App*** to ***Base.Theme.App***

And also tried files to ***invalid caches/restart method***.

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
```

This is xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout                         
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/nav_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

These are my error messages. It is given in preview error.

The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout (    Add constraint-layout library dependency to the project, Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
- android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
- android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
- android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
- android.support.design.widget.NavigationView (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
- android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
- android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)

Is there anything I could try to fix this?
Or do I have to reset everything?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37992187/gradle-sync-failed-could-not-find-constraint-layout1-0-0-alpha2

Comment: woe I've forgot to write that. I've already updated sdk management

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

Then  Read [**`AndroidX`**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) .

Your XML will -->

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
 <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
 <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
 <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
 <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
```

> The following classes could not be found: -
>   android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout

Then use

```
 implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
```

Comment: @JaesukPark Refactor->Migrate to AndroidX

Comment: When I add that it saids it is invalid statement.
Should I have to migrate in android x?

Comment: Wow. It really worked. So the problem was a androidX migration.
Actually I used API 28 first time. It reaaaally Helped!